# When running two decision trees one after another, both appear in same plot?

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree

I am visualizing three different decision trees

1. Normal tree
2. Tree with balanced data (using SMOTE)
3. Tree with weighted data

For all trees I am using the fancyrpartplot() and I have no error when plotting.

When I plot my first tree, everything is fine. Then I run my code for the SMOTE function and I plot my second desicion tree with the balanced data. This second tree is plotted only in 2/3 of the total plotting area...
When plotting my normal tree again, the normal tree is plotted underneath the SMOTE tree....

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I do not know why this happens and would appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Try to set an appropriate `par` prior to calling the tree plot. Something like `par(mfrow = c(1,1))`. Or call `dev.off()` and then plot the tree.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much :)